# Ruby-Rails serializer how to show different attributes on index vs show route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, routes, attributes

I'm using the JSONAPI gem, on the serializer class I want to show different attributes on the index route vs the show route. Is there a way to do this by detecting the request type in the serializer? I want to do this because a few of the columns are very long so having them appear on the index page for every result isn't ideal but showing the columns on the show/detail page is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not used to JSONAPI, I have only used [Active Model Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) and there you can just create different serializers or do the conditional rendering. But how about the example in [Rendering resources](http://jsonapi-rb.org/guides/getting_started/rails.html), looks like something you want.

```
class PostsController < ActionController::Base
  # ...

  def index
    render jsonapi: Posts.all, include: [:author, comments: [:author]],
           fields: { users: [:name, :email],
                     posts: [:title, :content] }
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: No problems, let me know how it went! I can recommend AMS if you are not completely stuck with JSONAPI. Also Netflix's fastjsonapi is quite popular and extremely fast and flexible to use.

Comment: Just an FYI, so far that method doesn't seem to work without some larger changes to the BaseSerializer class and API controller as it takes all model data and the attributes are only provided at the model_serialize.rb layer. There only seems to be the object itself available nothing of the request itself to know if its a post/get/show/index request. That's what I need to flex at this point.